# Is there a GCC flag to detect string literal concatenation?

Tags: c

I recently fixed a bug that was the result of something like

```
const char *arr[] = {
"string1", // Some comment
"string2",
"string3"  // Another comment
"string4",
"string5"
};
```

I.e., someone forgot a `,` after "string3", and "string3" and "string4" gets pasted together. Now, while this is perfectly legal code, is there a GCC warning flag, or other tool that could scan the code base for similar errors?

Comment: I highly doubt that there is such an option, because this is used in various places intentionally and would yield lot's of false positives.

Comment: That's like `if (a=5) DoSmth();` practically uncatchable.

Comment: String concatenation is done by the preprocessor.

Comment: What _may_ help you is explicitely stating the array size. Compilers or static analyzers may notice that you're not supplying enough elements.

Comment: I don't think there is such tool, but you can try `libclang` and write one yourself.

Comment: @ForceBru Well, gcc has a flag to warn about if (a=5). I's fine if it would give false positives, as just one scan of the code base would still be more efficient than doing it manually.

Comment: [Here are the preprocessor options for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html).

Comment: @stefan That won't work actually, the last element will value initialized (in C++ terms.)

Comment: @remyabel I know, but there still may be static analyzers out there that warn if things seem unusual (typical usage imho is with `{}, {0}` or the full list of elements). It is of course never an error.

Comment: @ForceBru Sane warning level will definitely warn about suspicious assignment, because the warning is easily fixable by adding explicit comparison with parenthesis.

Comment: Suitable unit test should detect this mistake, either directly testing the array, or indirectly by testing something which uses the array. Just because something is statically initialized data doesn't mean it doesn't need to be covered by unit tests.

Comment: If this is a worry, test for array size, or simply grep for newlines and spaces within quotes

Answer (score 1):

A basic 'tool' you could use is a preprocessor hack, but it's a very ugly solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int start = __LINE__;
const char *arr[] = {
"string1", //some comment
"string2",
"string3"  //another comment
"string4",
"string5"
};int end = __LINE__;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("arr length: %zu\n", sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
    printf("_assumed_ arr length: %d\n", (end - start - 2));
}
```

Comment: You're right - ugly ;)  I agree with [hyde (above)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744208/gcc-flag-to-detect-string-literal-concatenation): " Suitable unit test should detect this mistake, either directly testing the array, or indirectly by testing something which uses the array."

Comment: We had a similar problem with a func call `func(format, "foo" "bar")` and as the prototype was `func(char *, ...)` i.e. with var args, the gcc could not detect the missing `,`, concatenated the two string args w/o any warning and the proc SIGSEGV'ed due to mismatch of `format` string and args.

Answer (score 0):

GCC has such a warning:

> -Wtraditional (C and Objective-C only)
>
> Warn about certain constructs that behave differently in traditional and ISO C. Also warn about ISO C constructs that have no traditional C equivalent, and/or problematic constructs that should be avoided.
>
> .....
>
> - Usage of ISO string concatenation is detected.

Comment: What are you quoting?